Animated object subject to petrification
During our last session the Wizard cast the Animate objects spell on 10 Electrum coins. A few rounds later, one of those coins was petrified by a Gorgon (the DM pointed out that for the duration of the spell an animated object is a construct).
Then the game session was adjourned.
My question is: once the Animate objects spell ends, will the petrified coin remain a construct?
If not, will the coin remain petrified?
Or will it revert to its original form (Electrum)?

Extremely related: Can Polymorph end spells that require the target to be humanoid? and its duplicate, Is a spell suppressed or removed when the target temporarily becomes invalid?. Gorgon breath isn't a spell, but it has all the same issues and ambiguity.

There is no rule on it. Unofficial guidance is that petrification is suppressed while the coin is not a creature.
As explained in this answer on the opposite problem (an object that is turned into a creature), and in this answer the rules really only cover targeting for when a spell is cast, and there are no rules for what happens if a target of a condition becomes invalid later on. So your DM has to decide that. The unofficial guidance is that the condition will be supressed while the target is invalid, based on a statement by  Jeremy Crawford, the lead designer:

There's no rule governing what happens when a valid spell target temporarily becomes an invalid target. A good rule of thumb is that the spell is suppressed while the target is invalid.

The petrified condition does not protect its target from other spells ending. So when animate objects ends, the petrified coin will stop being a creature, and the DM has to make a call.
Following the unofficial guidance, at that point the coin would still be petrified, but the petrification would be suppressed, and the coin would turn into electrum again. However, were it to be re-animated, it would be a creature again, and the petrification not having been removed, only suppressed, would kick back in and re-petrify it.

PS What a show-off to use valuable electrum coins that could buy ink, when simple coppers or pebbles would do!

I’m assuming the inofficial [sic] guidance you’re referring to is the JC tweet from the linked Q&A. If so, please quote and link it (the actual tweet) rather than ambiguously referring to it.

At the level animate objects is available, the value of a few electrum for ink is negligible.  The real value of using electrum is to distract the DM.  While the DM is trying to figure out whether electrum coins count as silvered weapons, the players have more time to plan their next turn.

@Kirt I use tiny silver bee figurines. I think technically even silver objects are not silvered weapons for overcoming resistance, but neither me as the DM nor our other DM are insisting on that.

My player who is a bard uses faerie statuettes with a steel core and silver plating
